# jQuery: How to show this content

Tags: jquery

This may be little bit stupid question but let me explain

**html -> theContent**

```
<ul style="display:none">
   <li id="clx0"><div>the content1</div></li>
   <li id="clx1"><div>the content2</div></li>
   <li id="clx2"><div>the content3</div></li>
</ul>
```

and theContent display in loop div

```
<div class="bigcicing"></div>
<div class="bigcicing"></div>
<div class="bigcicing"><div>the content1</div></div>
<div class="bigcicing"></div>
<div class="bigcicing"></div>
<div class="bigcicing"><div>the content2</div></div>
<div class="bigcicing"></div>
<div class="bigcicing"></div>
<div class="bigcicing"><div>the content3</div></div>
<div class="bigcicing"></div>
```

right now my PROBLEMS is using jquery is like this

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
   var kuuk1 = $(".bigcicing:nth-child(3)");
   var kuuk2 = $(".bigcicing:nth-child(6)");
   var kuuk3 = $(".bigcicing:nth-child(9)");
   var cicing1 = $("ul li#clx0").html();
   var cicing2 = $("ul li#clx1").html();
   var cicing3 = $("ul li#clx2").html();
    $(kuuk1).html(cicing1);
    $(kuuk2).html(cicing2);
    $(kuuk3).html(cicing3);
});
```

BUT before my approach like this, but only show one theContent and repeated n times

```
$("ul li[id^="clx"]").each(function(index) {
   var leaksatu = $(this).html();
   var kuuk = $(".bigcicing:nth-child(3n)");
   $(kuuk).html(leaksatu);
});
```

I can't seem to find anything on google or in this site but I'm probably search for the wrong term. Any advice

Thanks

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agoraclx/gsLd2/)

Comment: mate,could u please be a little more clear.what exactly is your problem..??

Comment: the problem is using repeated var like var 1 , var 2 etc not best approach :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('ul li[id^="clx"]').each(function (index) {
    var leaksatu = $(this).html();
    var kuuk = $(".bigcicing:nth-child(" + ((index + 1) * 5) + "n)");
    $(kuuk).html(leaksatu);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MxTVB/)